# Horizontally scrollable table with Twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have a page with a table that can have different number of columns. It is product comparison page and user can select up to 10 products to compare.

I am using twitter bootstrap v2.1 with fixed layout + responsive. 
How can I make the table scrollable horizontally within container div?
Ideally I would also like to have the first column always visible (frozen).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually I solved the main problem this way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12" style="overflow: auto">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th><th>Column 4</th><th>Column 5</th>
                <th>Column 6</th><th>Column 7</th><th>Column 8</th><th>Column 9</th><th>Column 10</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row1 Column1</td><td>Row1 Column2</td><td>Row1 Column3</td><td>Row1 Column4</td><td>Row1 Column5</td>
                    <td>Row1 Column6</td><td>Row1 Column7</td><td>Row1 Column8</td><td>Row1 Column9</td><td>Row1 Column10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row2 Column1</td><td>Row2 Column2</td><td>Row2 Column3</td>    <td>Row2 Column4</td><td>Row2 Column5</td>
                    <td>Row2 Column6</td><td>Row2 Column7</td><td>Row2 Column8</td><td>Row2 Column9</td><td>Row2 Column10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row3 Column1</td><td>Row3 Column2</td><td>Row3 Column3</td><td>Row3 Column4</td><td>Row3 Column5</td>
                    <td>Row3 Column6</td><td>Row3 Column7</td><td>Row3 Column8</td><td>Row3 Column9</td><td>Row3 Column10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row4 Column1</td><td>Row4 Column2</td><td>Row4 Column3</td><td>Row4 Column4</td><td>Row4 Column5</td>
                    <td>Row4 Column6</td><td>Row4 Column7</td><td>Row4 Column8</td><td>Row4 Column9</td><td>Row4 Column10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row5 Column1</td><td>Row5 Column2</td><td>Row5 Column3</td><td>Row5 Column4</td><td>Row5 Column5</td>
                    <td>Row5 Column6</td><td>Row5 Column7</td><td>Row5 Column8</td><td>Row5 Column9</td><td>Row5 Column10</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if anyone know how to freeze first column I would really appreciate it

Comment: To fix a problem on the right side of the table, add this style: "max-width: none;" to table tag.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed columns and scrollbars for datatables

Get the `FixedHeader plug-in`
and 
then

> ```
> $(document).ready( function () {
>     var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
>         "sScrollX":       "100%",
>         "sScrollXInner":  "150%",
>         "sScrollY":       "250px",
>         "bScrollCollapse": true,
>         "bPaginate":       false
>     } );
>      new FixedColumns( oTable, {
>          "iColumns": 2
>      } );
> } );
> ```

[reference](http://www.datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/options)