# Bootstrap Horizontal Scrollable Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been struggling with this for a while now. I have a table in bootstrap that if it gets to wide I would like to make it scrollable so they can at least scroll to see the information.

My html is pretty simple just a table within a box

```
<div class='box'>
  <div class='box-header'>
    <h4>Title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class='box-content'>
    <table>
    <!--Table Stuff-->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I have tries the usual of setting a `width` and then an `overflow-x:scroll;` like so

```
table{
 width:100px;
 max-width:100px;
 overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

but nothing seems to work.

I have a jsFiddle set up here. http://jsfiddle.net/AHyuF/3/

Any help would be much, much appreciated!

Comment: Don't know if you solved this...
I had the same problem and found the solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272981/horizontally-scrollable-table-with-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 10):

or else you just have to add class "`table-responsive`" to table `div`

```
 <div class = "table-responsive">
 </div>
```

It will make table scrollable.

Answer (score 8):

Put the max width overflow on the `tableScroll` div (container) instead...

```
.tableScroll{
    width:200px;
    max-width:200px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Comment: This is on the container though...and I have some paging that happens that this will effect as well. I just want the table to scroll and not the container.

Comment: I came up with the same answer, Here is an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AHyuF/2/

Comment: I updated my fiddle to show what I do not want to scroll

Comment: I don't think overflow works on tables. Overflow only works on block level elements. Table elements aren't block elements.

Comment: Then that would be my answer...display:block;

Comment: creating a container div and adding `overflow-x:scroll` worked for me.  To the OP - I suggest you accept the answer or add an edit to your question clarifying what you are looking for that makes this answer not correct

Answer (score 3):

Please put style `overflow-x: scroll;` to the parent element of table, in this case `<div class='box-content'>`.

Here is the jsFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/AHyuF/38/

Comment: please find the link :  [http://jsfiddle.net/AHyuF/38/](http://jsfiddle.net/AHyuF/38/)

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a solution to table horizontal scrolling for Bootstrap 2.3.2, which I'd like to share. Can't take credit for it though; that goes to James Chambers, author of Bootstrapping MVC.

Just add this to your custom CSS file.

```
.table-responsive 
{   
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;   
    overflow-y: hidden;     
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #000000; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the table width as

```
table{
 width:200px;
 max-width:200px;
 overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

and add some more to table div class .box-content

```
.box-content {overflow-x:auto;}
```

it will work.
Please let me know if it works.